# Request path contains unescaped characters, in Mocha/chai testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Given is my code to test a post request with an Authorization header set to the jwt token and **a path parameter passed in to the post path, i.e. the id:5ee9b12ab08b6c3c58375a6d**

***Is there a better way to do this?***

```
const expect = require("expect");
const request = require("request");
const chai = require("chai");
let chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
let server = require("../app");
let should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Admin Priveleges", () => {
  describe("/Update Status", () => {
    it("Update membership and registration status", (done) => {
      chai
        .request(server)
        .post("/api​/v2​/user​/update-status​/5ee9b12ab08b6c3c58375a6d")
        .set('Authorization', "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZWU5YjEzN2IwOGI2YzNjNTgzNzVhNmUiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE1OTI0NjEyMjIyMDgsIm5hbWUiOiJVdGthcnNoIFNocml2YXN0YXZhIiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyMzc0ODIyfQ.M53gRzIppbhhLSCf9bD6xcdXfITiD1jUOzTlDqHK3is")
        .send({
          membership_status: "active",
          registration_status: "pending_approval",
          status_comment: "Good going"
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (should) console.log("****Status Updated Successfully****");
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    }).timeout(30000);
  });
});
```

***So this is my testing code and each time I run this for testing I get the following error:***

[image]

***How can I solve this error?***

Answer (score 0):

When I copy-pasted you 'url' in web console, it showed the `actual` string with the otherwise 'invisible' **`.`**

[image: screenshot]

`Test`:

```
context('Should not show "Request path contains unescaped characters, in Mocha/chai testing"', function() {
  it('POST /api/v2/user/update-status/5ee9b12ab08b6c3c58375a6d', function(done) {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .post('/api/v2/user/update-status/5ee9b12ab08b6c3c58375a6d')
      // .post('/api​/v2​/user​/update-status​/5ee9b12ab08b6c3c58375a6d') // with the 'hidden dots'
      .set('Authorization', "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZWU5YjEzN2IwOGI2YzNjNTgzNzVhNmUiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE1OTI0NjEyMjIyMDgsIm5hbWUiOiJVdGthcnNoIFNocml2YXN0YXZhIiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyMzc0ODIyfQ.M53gRzIppbhhLSCf9bD6xcdXfITiD1jUOzTlDqHK3is")
      .send({
        membership_status: "active",
        registration_status: "pending_approval",
        status_comment: "Good going"
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        // if (err) throw err;
        // if (should) console.log("****Status Updated Successfully****");
        // res.should.have.status(200);
        expect(res).to.have.status(404);
        
        done();
      });
  });
})
```

[image: screenshot2]